# Kubeadm why does my node not show up though kubelet says it joined?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform

I am setting up a Kubernetes deployment using auto-scaling groups and Terraform.  The kube master node is behind an ELB to get some reliability in case of something going wrong.  The ELB has the health check set to `tcp 6443`, and tcp listeners for 8080, 6443, and 9898.  All of the instances and the load balancer belong to a security group that allows all traffic between members of the group, plus public traffic from the NAT Gateway address.  I created my AMI using the following script (from the getting started guide)...

```
# curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key add -
# cat <<EOF > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list
deb http://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main
EOF
# apt-get update
# # Install docker if you don't have it already.
# apt-get install -y docker.io
# apt-get install -y kubelet kubeadm kubectl kubernetes-cni
```

I use the following user data scripts...

## kube master

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -rf /etc/kubernetes/*
rm -rf /var/lib/kubelet/*

kubeadm init \
  --external-etcd-endpoints=http://${etcd_elb}:2379 \
  --token=${token} \
  --use-kubernetes-version=${k8s_version} \
  --api-external-dns-names=kmaster.${master_elb_dns} \
  --cloud-provider=aws
until kubectl cluster-info
do
  sleep 1
done
kubectl apply -f https://git.io/weave-kube
```

## kube node

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -rf /etc/kubernetes/*
rm -rf /var/lib/kubelet/*

until kubeadm join --token=${token} kmaster.${master_elb_dns}
do
  sleep 1
done
```

Everything seems to work properly.  The master comes up and responds to kubectl commands, with pods for discovery, dns, weave, controller-manager, api-server, and scheduler.  kubeadm has the following output on the node...

```
Running pre-flight checks
<util/tokens> validating provided token
<node/discovery> created cluster info discovery client, requesting info from "http://kmaster.jenkins.learnvest.net:9898/cluster-info/v1/?token-id=eb31c0"
node/discovery> failed to request cluster info, will try again: [Get http://kmaster.jenkins.learnvest.net:9898/cluster-info/v1/?token-id=eb31c0: EOF]
<node/discovery> cluster info object received, verifying signature using given token
<node/discovery> cluster info signature and contents are valid, will use API endpoints [https://10.253.129.106:6443]
<node/bootstrap> trying to connect to endpoint https://10.253.129.106:6443
<node/bootstrap> detected server version v1.4.4
<node/bootstrap> successfully established connection with endpoint https://10.253.129.106:6443
<node/csr> created API client to obtain unique certificate for this node, generating keys and certificate signing request
<node/csr> received signed certificate from the API server:
Issuer: CN=kubernetes | Subject: CN=system:node:ip-10-253-130-44 | CA: false
Not before: 2016-10-27 18:46:00 +0000 UTC Not After: 2017-10-27 18:46:00 +0000 UTC
<node/csr> generating kubelet configuration
<util/kubeconfig> created "/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf"

Node join complete:
* Certificate signing request sent to master and response
  received.
* Kubelet informed of new secure connection details.

Run 'kubectl get nodes' on the master to see this machine join.
```

Unfortunately, running `kubectl get nodes` on the master only returns itself as a node.  The only interesting thing I see in /var/log/syslog is

```
Oct 27 21:19:28 ip-10-252-39-25 kubelet[19972]: E1027 21:19:28.198736   19972 eviction_manager.go:162] eviction manager: unexpected err: failed GetNode: node 'ip-10-253-130-44' not found
Oct 27 21:19:31 ip-10-252-39-25 kubelet[19972]: E1027 21:19:31.778521   19972 kubelet_node_status.go:301] Error updating node status, will retry: error getting node "ip-10-253-130-44": nodes "ip-10-253-130-44" not found
```

I am really not sure where to look...

Comment: did you ever figure this out? i have the same issue.

Comment: I should have come back to this when it happened!  My memory is a bit foggy, but if I remember correctly this was caused because the AWS cloud provider was setting the nodename to the aws instance id instead of a resolvable dns name.

Answer (score 6):

The Hostnames of the two machines (master and the node) should be different. You can check them by running `cat /etc/hostname`.  If they do happen to be the same, edit that file to make them different and then do a `sudo reboot` to apply the changes. Otherwise kubeadm will not be able to differentiate between the two machines and it will show as a single one in kubectl get nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , I faced the same problem.

I resolved by:

killall kubelet

run the kubectl join command again

and start the kubelet service